# Magento Widget Variables

Tags: magento

I've build an own widget using the product_link core widget.

```
{{widget type="brandpage_header_b/Header" brand_header_logo="wysiwyg/myimage.png" brand_header_img="wysiwyg/bmyimage.jpg" brand_header_title="titel" brand_header_text="text" template="path/to/template.phtml"}}
```

Now I want to call some of the variables within the template.phtml.

I tried:

```
<?php $brand_header_logo = $this->getData('category_id'); 
echo $brand_header_logo; 
?>
```

But that doesn't work. Can anybody explain me how to get the Widget-Variables into the .phtml template? Appriciate your Help a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your logic. If you want to receive **brand_header_logo** variable from your widget declaration, then use it in getData method.

```
<?php $brand_header_logo = $this->getData('brand_header_logo'); 
echo $brand_header_logo; 
?>
```

But right now you're trying to get **category_id**, which you don't have in your widget.